# Symfony 5 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' In C:\Users\public\index.php on line 15

Tags: server, symfony5

I try to start a new project symfony 5 simple. When I start the server "symfony server: start", I have this answer:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' In C:\Users\Philippe\Documents\my_project_name\public\index.php on line 15.
I have windws 10, PHP 7.4.3, wamp server but its off.

I show you my terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple php5.6 does not support Null coalescing operator (??). This operator is available from PHP7+ ([php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op))

Solution 1:

- Upgrade your PHP version to ^7

Solution 2:

- Change code
- PHP 7+ `$username = $loggedUser ?? 'nobody';`
- PHP 5.6 `$username = isset($loggedUser) ? $loggedUser : 'nobody';`

both is equivalent, return logged user if set, otherwise nobody.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the output that you are running "PHP cgi v5.6.40".  Run `symfony local:php:list` and see what is available to be able to be run. You need to install PHP 7.4 as php-fpm (if available on WAMP), or php-cgi.  The Symfony Server can't use the cli version to run webpages.

`symfony local:php:refresh` may also help, or install other versions of PHP.

```
> symfony local:php:list

# You'll see all supported SAPIs (CGI, FastCGI, etc.) for each version.
# FastCGI (php-fpm) is used when possible; then CGI (which acts as a FastCGI
# server as well), and finally, the server falls back to plain CGI.
```

from: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#selecting-a-different-php-version